# Use only non-NA cells to replace cells in another column

Tags: r, replace, rstudio, swap

long time listener, first time caller, so I apologize if I'm missing critical information in the post or in general.

In short, I have two columns, one of which has every cell filled (behavior). The other (game) is mostly NA except for a few cells, but what is in each cell is not necessarily the same. For every non-NA in game, no matter the content, I want to use it to replace the data in the corresponding row in the behavior column.

Here is the data:

```
behavior<-c("run","jump","play","walk","jump","walk","run","play","jump","jump")
game<-c(NA,"tag",NA,NA,NA,"slide",NA,"tag",NA,"hopscotch")

    test<-data.frame(behavior,game)

behavior    game
1   run     NA
2   jump    tag
3   play    NA
4   walk    NA
5   jump    NA
6   walk    slide
7   run     NA
8   play    tag
9   jump    NA
10  jump    hopscotch
```

I want it to look like:

```
behavior    game
1   run     NA
2   tag     tag
3   play    NA
4   walk    NA
5   jump    NA
6   slide   slide
7   run     NA
8   tag     tag
9   jump    NA
10  hopscotch   hopscotch
```

I've tried writing functions using something like !(test$game==NA) with if/else but I think I'm missing something fundamental here. This seems fairly straightforward but after scouring stackoverflow I've seen a ton of advice on how to replace NAs but none on how to use only non-NAs to replace a cell that's already filled. For curiosity's sake I'd also be interested if there's a way to swap the cell values, so the second row would be tag/jump instead of tag/tag. Happy to offer any additional info/clarifications, and any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: `test$behavior[!is.na(test$game)] <- test$game[!is.na(test$game)]`

Comment: Or `transform(test, behavior = ifelse(is.na(game), behavior, game))` provided `test<-data.frame(behavior,game, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: So fast and simple--thank you so much!!

Comment: If you want to create a new column and preserve the original data you can do `transform(test, behavior1 = ifelse(is.na(game), behavior, game))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to SO.

Thanks for providing some sample data, that's really helpful!

I'd personally tackle this using the `dplyr` package and the `coalesce()` function (if you're familiar with `SQL` you may recognise that function, if not, don't worry!).

What `coalecse()` function does is take the first non-NA value across two or more vectors. You can use it on it's own or, my preference, inside the `mutate()` function (also from `dplyr`) which is useful for creating/modifying columns inside a data frame:

```r
library(dplyr)

behavior<-c("run","jump","play","walk","jump","walk","run","play","jump","jump")
game<-c(NA,"tag",NA,NA,NA,"slide",NA,"tag",NA,"hopscotch")

# Make the data frame, using stringsAsFactors = FALSE to make sure our data
# get treated as characters, not factors 
test <- data.frame(behavior = behavior, game = game, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dplyr::mutate(
     test,
     behavior = dplyr::coalesce(game, behavior)
)

    behavior      game
1        run      <NA>
2        tag       tag
3       play      <NA>
4       walk      <NA>
5       jump      <NA>
6      slide     slide
7        run      <NA>
8        tag       tag
9       jump      <NA>
10 hopscotch hopscotch
```

To help visualise this a bit, let's make a new column (rather than overwriting `behavior`):

```r
mutate(
     test,
     new = coalesce(game, behavior)
)

   behavior      game       new
1       run      <NA>       run
2      jump       tag       tag
3      play      <NA>      play
4      walk      <NA>      walk
5      jump      <NA>      jump
6      walk     slide     slide
7       run      <NA>       run
8      play       tag       tag
9      jump      <NA>      jump
10     jump hopscotch hopscotch
```

So `coalesce()` is looking at `game` and then `behavior`, if there's a value in `game` is uses it, if there's not it looks at `behavior` and uses that value instead (and if there was no value in either, it would use `NA`).

If you like this approach I'd recommend looking at the (excellent) R for Data Science book (free online here: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/) and the `tidyverse` collection of packages (https://www.tidyverse.org/).

Comment: Better idea to create a new column & preserve the original data, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Reading your data as strings and not factors

```
test<- data.frame(behavior,game, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

We can use simple `ifelse` with `transform` where the value of `behavior` is changed based on `NA` value `game` column.

```
transform(test, behavior = ifelse(is.na(game), behavior, game))

#    behavior      game
#1        run      <NA>
#2        tag       tag
#3       play      <NA>
#4       walk      <NA>
#5       jump      <NA>
#6      slide     slide
#7        run      <NA>
#8        tag       tag
#9       jump      <NA>
#10 hopscotch hopscotch
```

---

`factors` are internally stored as numbers, if you don't read them as characters then the same code would produce

```
test<- data.frame(behavior,game)
transform(test, behavior = ifelse(is.na(game), behavior, game))
#   behavior      game
#1         3      <NA>
#2         3       tag
#3         2      <NA>
#4         4      <NA>
#5         1      <NA>
#6         2     slide
#7         3      <NA>
#8         3       tag
#9         1      <NA>
#10        1 hopscotch
```

which would be very confusing and difficult to debug. Alternatively, we can override the factor values by using `as.character` which would give the expected output.

```
transform(test, behavior = ifelse(is.na(game), as.character(behavior), 
                                               as.character(game)))
```

Comment: Could you explain why it's important to read the data as strings, and not as factors?

Comment: Definitely, great answer! I just thought it'd be useful to show why to avoid stringsAsFactors in this case